# ¿Como buscar registros de una tabla en excel al azar con solo ingresar la cantidad de registros?

Tags: excel

[image: Quiero ingresar un numero en la celda B8 y al presionar enter me aparezca en la otra hoja llamada "REPORTE" los registros de manera aleatoria (incluyendo data de item, descripción y cantidad) según la cantidad de registros que ingrese previamente en la celda B8 del libro "DATA". Adjunto imágenes.]

ingresar un numero en la celda B8 y al presionar enter me aparezca en la otra hoja llamada "REPORTE" los registros de manera aleatoria (incluyendo data de item, descripción y cantidad) según la cantidad de registros que ingrese previamente en la celda B8 del libro "DATA"

[image: Aqui debe mostrarse el resultado de la data segun la cantidad de registros que se ingreso previamente en la hoja "DATA"]

Comment: Para esto necesitas una macro en VBA.

Comment: Buena respuesta, me ayuda mucho eh gracias.

Comment: Lo sé, es bastante buena. Piensa que esta comunidad no es un sitio donde te desarrollen código gratis, sino que se resuelven dudas específicas de programación. Lo que quieres hacer se tiene que hacer con una macro en VBA, así que tendrás que escribir el código tu mismo. Si en algún punto concreto y específico te atascas, vuelves aquí y preguntas.